# Getting not data while selecting accorading to id in android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have try this query in **DBAdater.java** class:

```
 public Cursor getUserName(int userId) {

    Cursor c = db.query(REGISTER_TABLE, new String[] { REGISTER_ID,
            REGISTER_UN }, REGISTER_ID + " = " +userId,null,  null, null,
            null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

**Or**

```
public Cursor get_user(int id) {
    return db.query(REGISTER_TABLE,
            new String[] { REGISTER_ID, REGISTER_UN }, REGISTER_ID + "="

            + "'" + id + "'", null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

**Test.java**  Getting username

```
Cursor clogin = db.getUserName(userId);
Log.i("user name  with repect to user id ", ""+clogin.getString(clogin.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.RID)));
```

When i run this , I get this errors:

```
04-30 14:18:52.925: E/AndroidRuntime(639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 14:18:52.925: E/AndroidRuntime(639): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.linkplus/com.android.Hello.test.test}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 14:18:52.925: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
......
......
04-30 14:18:52.925: E/AndroidRuntime(639): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 14:18:52.925: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at com.android.Hello.test.Profiles.getUserName(Profiles.java:63)
04-30 14:18:52.925: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at com.android.Hello.test.Profiles.onCreate(Profiles.java:51)
04-30 14:18:52.925: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
```

Please Point out what is the error of this code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your query like

```
Cursor c = db.query(REGISTER_TABLE, new String[] { REGISTER_ID,
            REGISTER_UN }, REGISTER_ID + "=?", new String[]{userId},  null, null,
            null, null);
```

Also in **text.java** check for the null cursor

```
Cursor clogin = db.getUserName(userId);
if(clogin != null) {
Log.i("user name  with repect to user id ", ""+clogin.getString(clogin.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.RID)));

}
```

Comment: same error again occurs. I am doing this, 
  int loginId = loginPrefs.getInt(LOGINID, 0);
  String id = String.valueOf(loginId);

  Cursor clogin = db.test(id);
  if (clogin != null) {
   Log.i("user name  with repect to user id ",
     ""
       + clogin.getString(clogin
         .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.REGISTER_UN)));

  }

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the query isn't returning any values, it has to be some error in database, or most likely, in the query string .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can use this method

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Your Query without semicolon", selectionargs);
```

in your case

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select REGISTER_ID,REGISTER_UN from REGISTER_TABLE where REGISTER_ID="+userId,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may it works

```java
 Cursor c = db.query(REGISTER_TABLE, 
                     new String[] { REGISTER_ID, REGISTER_UN }, 
                     REGISTER_ID + " = " +userId, 
                     null,
                     null, 
                     null, 
                     null);
```